# Generics and getClass() as parameters

Tags: java, java-7

In my sample code below I'm trying to pass an object of a particular type and serialise it to Json.

```
protected <S> ResponseObject postJson(String url, S object) throws IOException {
    return post(url, getString(object, object.getClass()));
}

private <S> String getString(S object, Class<S> clazz) {
    // some code that relies on object being of type clazz
}
```

I get a compiler error:

```
method getString in class PPServerRequestJob<T> cannot be applied to given types;
    return post(url, getString(object, object.getClass()));
                     ^
  required: S#1,Class<S#1>
  found: S#2,Class<CAP#1>
  reason: inferred type does not conform to lower bound(s)
    inferred: CAP#1
    lower bound(s): S#2
  where S#1,S#2,T are type-variables:
    S#1 extends Object declared in method <S#1>getString(S#1,Class<S#1>)
    S#2 extends Object declared in method <S#2>postJson(String,S#2)
    T extends PPBaseResult declared in class PPServerRequestJob
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ? extends Object
```

I'm running on Android, so using Java 7.

I can get rid of the error by casing `object.getClass()` to `Class<S>` - but I don't see why that is necessary. `object.getClass()` returns `Class<? extends S>`, so `object` should meet that requirement as it is guaranteed to be a subclass of S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `object.getClass()` returns `Class<? extends S>`, so object should meet that requirement as it is guaranteed to be a subclass of S.

This is correct, however your second argument is of type `Class<S>` not `Class<? extends S>` which cannot be implicitly cast.

In your example the compiler will substitute S with whatever the declared class is that is used to call the function, however it could be a subclass. getClass() returns the concrete class. For instance consider the following:

```
Animal a = new Cat();
postJson("http://foo.com", a);
```

This results in the following implementation:

```
protected ResponseObject postJson(String url, Animal object) throws IOException {
    return post(url, getString(object, object.getClass() /* Cat.class */));
}

private String getString(Animal object, Class<Animal> clazz) {
    // some code that relies on object being of type clazz
}
```

Here you see the problem where the call to `getString` is trying to implicitly cast `Class<Cat>` to `Class<Animal>`. To fix this you need to change it to the following:

```
private <S> String getString(S object, Class<? extends S> clazz)
```